# nginx tests proper aliased file, then serves file from wrong location

Tags: nginx

I have this server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.app;
    root /opt/project/public/src/;

    charset utf-8;

    location ~ ^/dashboard/?(.*)$ {
       alias /opt/project/dashboard/src;
       try_files /$1 /testindex.html;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/project.app-error.log debug;
    rewrite_log on;

}
```

and this dir structure:

```
/opt/project/dashboard/src/
    test.svg
    testindex.html
```

When I go to `http://localhost/dashboard/test.svg` it works fine,
but if I goto `http://localhost/dashboard/testing` I want it to serve `/opt/project/dashboard/src/` but instead the debug shows this:

```
2017/06/16 19:36:11 [debug] 385#0: *46 http request line: "GET /dashboard/testing HTTP/1.1"
2017/06/16 19:36:11 [debug] 385#0: *46 http uri: "/dashboard/testing"
2017/06/16 19:36:11 [debug] 385#0: *46 http script copy: "/opt/project/dashboard/src/"
2017/06/16 19:36:11 [debug] 385#0: *46 http script capture: "testing"
2017/06/16 19:36:11 [debug] 385#0: *46 trying to use file: "testing" "/opt/project/dashboard/src/testing"
2017/06/16 19:36:11 [debug] 385#0: *46 trying to use file: "testindex.html" "/opt/project/dashboard/src/testindex.html"
2017/06/16 19:36:11 [debug] 385#0: *46 internal redirect: "testindex.html?"
2017/06/16 19:36:11 [debug] 385#0: *46 rewrite phase: 1
2017/06/16 19:36:11 [debug] 385#0: *46 test location: "/robots.txt"
2017/06/16 19:36:11 [debug] 385#0: *46 test location: ~ "^/dashboard/?(.*)$"
2017/06/16 19:36:11 [debug] 385#0: *46 using configuration ""
2017/06/16 19:36:11 [debug] 385#0: *46 http filename: "/opt/project/public/src/testindex.html"
```

(relevant parts of log only for brevity)

And it gives a 404 (or will serve the wrong file if I do put it into `public/src`).  It shows it tested the existing testindex.html file, but then goes off redirects and tries to serve it from the `public/src` dir.  I don't want it to serve anything from `public/src` at that path.  Why won't it send the `testindex.html` in `dashboard/src`?  I've been struggling with this for hours trying many different configurations.

EDIT:
I changed the try_files to: `try_files /$1 /dashboard/testindex.html;`. This was the result:

```
2017/06/16 20:04:08 [debug] 464#0: *65 trying to use file: "/dashboard/testindex.html" "/opt/project/dashboard/src/dashboard/testindex.html"
2017/06/16 20:04:08 [debug] 464#0: *65 internal redirect: "/dashboard/testindex.html?"
2017/06/16 20:04:08 [debug] 464#0: *65 rewrite phase: 1
2017/06/16 20:04:08 [debug] 464#0: *65 test location: ~ "^/dashboard/?(.*)$"
2017/06/16 20:04:08 [debug] 464#0: *65 using configuration "^/dashboard/?(.*)$"
2017/06/16 20:04:08 [debug] 464#0: *65 try files phase: 11
2017/06/16 20:04:08 [debug] 464#0: *65 http script copy: "/opt/project/dashboard/src"
2017/06/16 20:04:08 [debug] 464#0: *65 http script copy: "/"
2017/06/16 20:04:08 [debug] 464#0: *65 http script capture: "testindex.html"
2017/06/16 20:04:08 [debug] 464#0: *65 trying to use file: "/testindex.html" "/opt/project/dashboard/src/testindex.html"
2017/06/16 20:04:08 [debug] 464#0: *65 try file uri: "/testindex.html"
2017/06/16 20:04:08 [debug] 464#0: *65 http script copy: "/opt/project/dashboard/src"
2017/06/16 20:04:08 [debug] 464#0: *65 http filename: "/opt/project/dashboard/src/testindex.html"
```

And it seems to be working, but I don't understand what's happening, it's still doing the redirect, but it's looking at the wrong path, so not sure how it's getting it right or what's up with it. @confused

Comment: The last element of the `try_files` statement is a URI and causes an internal redirect. Which is why you need to use `/dashboard` in front of it. 
See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: That explains the 500 I got from the recursion when testindex.html isn't there, it gets to the url, and tries again, over and over